# PHP Redirect inside IF statement not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner in PHP, this is my first time posting, I've looked everywhere, but can't seem to find the issue/solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much!!

I am trying to redirect my login page on execution to a profile page (index.php). The else statement executes and error is echoed as per my code, but the code within the second if statement is not working. This code has worked for me in another project, but doesn't seem to work on this one.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    require 'db.php';
    

    
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'] )){
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `volunteer_form` WHERE `email`=? AND `password`=? ";
            $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute(array($email,$password));
            $row = $query->rowCount();
            $fetch = $query->fetch();
            if($row > 0) {
                $_SESSION['email'] = $fetch['email'];
                $_SESSION['password'] = $fetch['password'];
                header("location: index.php");

            }
        
    

    }else {
        echo "error";
    }

    }
?>
```

Comment: echo $row and see the content

Comment: You should have an `exit()` after the header redirect, otherwise execution will continue. Have you checked that you haven't already sent anything to the browser before your redirect? If you've already sent output, you'll get "Headers already sent" if you have error reporting enabled.

Comment: You appear to be storing passwords in plain text form - that is a very bad idea. Use `password_hash()` to store them, and `password_verify()` to check them.

Comment: Thank you ALL so much, your replies were confirmation that the code itself was correct (apart from the password_hash that I now added, ty @droopsnoot) , I figured it out, I was missing the name attribute on the login page itself. Much appreciated :))

Comment: Your code is sensible to SQL injection. Use parametrized queries.

Comment: @JoelCrypto, where do you see that? The OP _is_ using a parameterised query, using `prepare()` and passing their variables into `execute()`. I presume you meant "vulnerable" rather than "sensible"?

Comment: The code has been edited meanwhile.